# How do I handle a null value in a list when filling this dropdown button?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a flutter package to query SQL and return a list of allowed connections. If the user has no allowed connections, then it will return:

```
[{ServerName: null, ServerIP: null, DBName: null, PortNum: null, Status: null}]
```

How do I handle this case for a dropdown button and still show the user the hint 'Choose server'? This code will fire on initialization and on the user changing their username in the form field, so you can assume it will fire many times.

**The code:**

```
class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> serverList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState(); //Run this first
    initialize();
  }

  void initialize() async {
    serverList = await db.getServerList(username: userController.text);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  //...

  DropdownButton<String>(
    value: selectedServer,
    hint: const Text('Choose server'),
    items: serverList.map((value) {
      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        value: value['ServerName'],
        child: Text(value['ServerName']),
      );
    }).toList(),
    onChanged: onServerChanged,
    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
  ),
}
```

**Current error (points to `child: Text(value['ServerName'])`):**

> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: Uh, filter it from the list?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz how would I do that in flutter?

Comment: Don't show serverList.  Show serverList.where( null check here ).toList()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  String? selectedServer;
  
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> serverList = <Map<String, dynamic>>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    unawaited(delayedFunction());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: serverList.isEmpty
              ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
              : serverList.any(
                  (Map<String, dynamic> element) => element.containsValue(null),
                )
                  ? const Text("User has no allowed connections")
                  : DropdownButton<String>(
                      value: selectedServer,
                      hint: const Text("Choose server"),
                      items: serverList.map((Map<String, dynamic> value) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: value["ServerName"],
                          child: Text(value["ServerName"]),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (String? value) {
                        selectedServer = value;
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                    ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> delayedFunction() async {
    await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
    serverList = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
      <String, dynamic>{
        "ServerName": "Server 1",
        "ServerIP": "1.1.1.1",
        "DBName": "DB 1",
        "PortNum": "1",
        "Status": "OK"
      },
      <String, dynamic>{
        "ServerName": "Server 2",
        "ServerIP": "2.2.2.2",
        "DBName": "DB 2",
        "PortNum": "2",
        "Status": "OK"
      }
    ];
    // serverList = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
    //   <String, dynamic>{
    //     "ServerName": null,
    //     "ServerIP": null,
    //     "DBName": null,
    //     "PortNum": null,
    //     "Status": null
    //   }
    // ];
    setState(() {});
    return Future<void>.value();
  }
}
```